# How to iterate loop in reverse order in Scala

Tags: scala

I want result as `20 19 18 ..` and so on but it prints nothing,

```
 def iterateForLoop(i: Int): Unit ={
        for(start <- 20 to i){
          println(start);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default step of range functions in Scala is 1, the numbers ate iterated in increasing order. If `i` is less than 20, the sequence of numbers will be empty.

If you want to iterate in decreasing order, you have to specify the iteration step manually using `by` method:

```
def iterateForLoop(i: Int): Unit = for (start <- 20 to i by -1) println(start)
```